# How to create a test page to check the SQL Server database connection on online hosting site (plesk)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, web-hosting

I want to make sure that my database is connected with my site or not. I created this project in ASP.NET MVC. My project is working fine on my local machine, but after I deployed my project to the hosting site, there are two problems occurring:

1. Login and registration page is not loading
2. I think it is due to database connection or connection string problem.

Here is the [Home Page](http://www.starbuy.pk/)

In the Home page menu, there is an item **My accounts**. In "My accounts" option there are [Login Link](http://www.starbuy.pk/Account/Login) and [Registration link](http://www.starbuy.pk/Account/Register)

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=IP address\.MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=StarBuy;Integrated Security=SSPI;"  
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="StarBuyEntities1" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IP adrees\.MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=StarBuy;user id=abc;password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your local application with connection string to the remote database and see if it is working. This should help to know if the problem is with connection string.